# How Can I Map JSON to JAX-B Object?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, rest

I have some incoming JSON that I need to map to a JAXB object.  Do I need to convert the JSON to XML and then populate the JAXB object, or can I map the JSON directly to the object?  In either case, can someone tell me what is the best library for doing this?

Comment: If you have an incoming JSON from a service provider, they should already have a file describing their format. Just ask them for an XSD or JSON schema. When it comes to JSON->POJO mapping, you can take a look at jsonschema2pojo: http://code.google.com/p/jsonschema2pojo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

> Do I need to convert the JSON to XML and then populate the JAXB
>   object, or can I map the JSON directly to the object?

You do not need to convert the JSON to XML before you hand the input to a JAXB (JSR-222) implementation.  If you are using the Jersey implementation (and probably others), you can set up your JAX-RS method like the following and JAXB will be used for both XML and JSON processing.

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("{id}")
public Customer read(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    return entityManager.find(Customer.class, id);
}
```

JAX-RS implementations have a `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` mechanism that allow you to override the default conversion.  I am not aware of Gson having any support for JAXB annotations.  Jackson is a object-to-JSON library that offers [support for a subset of JAXB annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations) ([maybe regrettably](https://twitter.com/cowtowncoder/status/183984609556578304)).  EclipseLink MOXy is a JAXB implementation, that has been [extended to support JSON-binding](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/json-binding-with-eclipselink-moxy.html).  For an example of using it in a JAX-RS environment see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

Answer (score 0):

[gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is a flexible library that can convert JSON string to equivalent Java objects including pre-existing Java objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jackson, You could look at the JacksonJAXBAnnotations here http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations

Answer (score 0):

As a lightweight approach, you can use StAXON - JSON via StAX, https://github.com/beckchr/staxon/. StAXON provides support for JAXB, see https://github.com/beckchr/staxon/wiki/Using-JAXB.

With StAXON, binding a JAXB-annotated model to JSON is as simple as

```
JsonXMLMapper<Person> mapper = new JsonXMLMapper<Person>(Person.class);
Person person = mapper.readObject(input);
...
mapper.writeObject(output, person);
```

StAXON also supports JAX-RS, see https://github.com/beckchr/staxon/wiki/Using-JAX-RS.